# Who are the dark-coloured inhabitants in this Rig Veda verse?

Tags: rig-veda

The Rig Veda has a verse that says:

> "Through fear of thee [Agni] the **dark-coloured inhabitants** fled, not waiting for battle, when, O Agni (fire) burning brightly for Puru, and destroying the cities, thou didst shine." (VII, 5, 3)

Who are the dark-coloured inhabitants?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Oxford translation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/019068500X) by Stephanie W. Jamison and Joel P. Brereton, the verse is referring to [Dasyus](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Dasyus). As the translators note, it's not referring to dark-skinned people but people that represent powers of darkness.

> **VII.5 (521) Agni Vaiśvānara**
>
> Vasiṣṭha Maitrāvaruṇi
>
> 9 verses: triṣṭubh
>
> The hymn invokes Agni as both the fire on earth and the sun in heaven.
>   More specifically, Agni is a tribal fire, which here represents an
>   aggregation of clans in the Pūru tribe (vs. 3). This hymn thus accords
>   with VII.19.3, in which Indra also supports the Pūru tribe, but
>   contrasts with VII.18.13, in which Indra supports Sudās, the enemy of
>   the Pūru. As Proferes (2007: 46–49) details, it is as a tribal fire
>   and as the sun that Agni is called Vaiśvānara, a name repeated in each
>   of the first five verses and then again in the last two (8–9).
>
> The hymn begins with a statement of Agni's presence in heaven and on
>   earth, nurtured by both the gods and priests (vs. 1). In the second
>   verse Agni is called the master of both flowing and pooling waters, a
>   theme echoed in verse 8, the second to last verse, in which Agni is
>   asked to send the "refreshing drink," which might be the rain for
>   humans or the soma for the gods or both. Having descended to earth,
>   Agni's radiance extends to the Ārya clans (vs. 2cd). **In verse 3 the
>   *víśaḥ...aśiknīḥ* "dark clans" are Dasyus (vs. 6), but they are not dark
>   because they are "dark-skinned," as the description is often
>   interpreted, but rather because they represent powers of darkness
>   opposed to the Āryas** (cf. Hock 1999). **Note that the brilliance of Agni
>   in 3cd breaks apart the "dark clans" and, as light, disperses
>   darkness**. Or likewise **in verse 6 Agni drives away the Dasyus,
>   providing a "broad light" for Āryas**. As fire and sun, Agni extends his
>   light throughout the worlds (vs. 4). In verse 5, the middle verse of
>   the hymn, the poet concretizes Agni as the present sacrificial fire,
>   who guards and prospers the different communities and as both the
>   sacrificial fire and the sun, both of which appear in the early
>   morning as beacons of the day.
>
> 1. Bring forth a song to the mighty Agni, to the spoked wheel of heaven and earth, who as Vaiśvānara has grown strong in the lap of all the immortals through the watchful (priests).
> 2. Sought after in heaven, Agni has been placed on earth as the leader of the rivers and the bull of standing waters. He radiates outward
>      toward the clans descended from Manu: Vaiśvānara having grown strong
>      according to his wish.
> 3. The **dark clans** went breaking ranks, leaving their supplies, from fear of you, o Vaiśvānara, **when you shone, breaking their strongholds**,
>      blazing for Pūru, o Agni.
> 4. Heaven and earth, (each) in its three parts, follow your commandment, o Agni Vaiśvānara. You stretch throughout the two
>      world-halves with your radiance, blazing with your inexhaustible
>      blaze.
> 5. Resounding ghee-rich songs—bellowing tawny mares—follow you, Agni, the lord of settlements, the charioteer of riches, Vaiśvānara, the
>      beacon of the dawns and of the days.
> 6. The good (gods) installed their lordship in you, for they find pleasure in your resolve, o you having Mitra's might. **You drove the
>      Dasyus away from their home, o Agni, giving birth to broad light for
>      the Ārya.**
> 7. Being born in the highest heaven, at once you protect the fold on every side like Vāyu. Giving birth to living beings, you cry out,
>      doing service to their descendants, Jātavedas.
> 8. Send the heaven-bright refreshing drink for us, o Agni Vaiśvānara, o Jātavedas, by which you swell your bounty and broad fame for the
>      pious mortal, o you who grant all wishes.
> 9. Bind wealth that brings many cattle to our generous patrons, o Agni, as well as the prize of victory worthy of fame. O Vaiśvānara,
>      along with the Rudras and Vasus, offer great protection to us, o Agni.

Comment: Are there more descriptions of dasayus anywhere else?

Comment: There are tons of mentions in the Rigveda. See the Introduction to the Oxford translation starting [page 54](https://books.google.com/books?id=fgzVAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA54#v=twopage&q&f=false). @GopalAnantharaman

Comment: @sv. That's interesting, didn't expect Western Indologists to say that "dark colored" means "evil."

Comment: Dark skin is actually literally 'darker' btw

Comment: Black skin means evil